# Two distros (Arch and Manjaro vs Mint) have bash located in different directories. How can I accomodate this in a bash script?

Tags: bash, arch-linux, linux-mint, directory

I've been mostly using Manjaro and Arch recently, but I'm trying to debug some possible hardware issues on Mint.

I have a number of bash scripts that no longer work in mint, because they start with `#!/usr/bin/bash`, but Mint has bash located at `/bin/bash`. Is there a way to incorporate some sort of redirect without having to change all my scripts?

For example, one of my first scripts I wrote to start practicing was just this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -x
cmatrix -bC red
```

Removing the `/usr` portion allows it to run fine in Mint, but is there a way to keep the same script and run it in both distros?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a relevant Q&A on Stack Overflow, See [What is the preferred Bash shebang?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376206/4500798), but I can’t find a good one here.

If you want your script to find `bash` anywhere on the `PATH`, whether `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc., use

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

(This assumes `/usr/bin/env` exists.)

On most Linux distributions though, including those you mention, it’s safe to use

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Some distributions *also* have `/usr/bin/bash`, but that’s the result of the [“`/usr` merge”](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) — `/bin` and `/usr/bin` now have the same contents in these distributions.

Comment: Yeah, I was hesitant to post on Stack Overflow as it seems more of a Linux thing than a scripting thing. If anything, I suppose I could put a symlink to direct per distro if the other one doesn't like the change.

Answer (score 0):

The following will require a one time change.  `#!/usr/bin/env bash` will search your PATH for bash.  You'll have to `set -x` separately though.

Comment: Sorry, not sure how that helps?

This is my ``echo $PATH`` output: ```$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games```


Edit: I was going to post on stackexchange, but I thought this was a distro issue. Should I head over there instead?

Comment: You can have multiple versions of bash on a server.  Production scripts may want to use the bash that comes installed on the server and you may want a newer version of bash for other scripts.  For a detailed discussion, Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365130/what-is-the-difference-between-usr-bin-env-bash-and-usr-bin-bash